# Align button text on side of png image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put some text on the right side of this png but for some reason it is showing below the image instead of showing on the side. 
Here is the bootply http://www.bootply.com/DaWdC87WaQ

```
.btn-default.btn1 {
 box-shadow: none;
 text-decoration: none !important;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 26px;
 font: bold 12px/30px 'Verdana';
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin: 0;
 text-shadow: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 color: #ffffff;
 background: #F66733;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.85s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.85s ease-out;
 transition: all 0.85s ease-out;
 width: 20%;
 height: 100px;
 }
```

HTML

```
        <div>
              <a style="font-size:20px;" class="btn-default btn1" href="#"><img src="http://oi57.tinypic.com/k973n4.jpg">Heading 1</a>
              <a style="font-size:20px;" class="btn-default btn1" href="#"><img src="http://oi60.tinypic.com/2uoiedc.jpg">Heading 2  </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: please post the code in your question as well. This helps future visitors to understand the problem even when your bootply has disappeared.

Comment: in your bootply, i see a key with "Heading 1" to the right of it (not below it)

Comment: see the second button where I have a road and the heading 2 is showing below the road png.

Comment: When I look at this in bootply, both buttons have an image on the left and text on the right.

Comment: If I narrow my browser, I can get the left button to have text to the right but the right button to have text  beneath.

Comment: Very simple, the buttons aren't big enough with `width: 20%` on some screen so the text will wrap.

Comment: But I don't want to increase the width. This will be a four column thing so 25% width for each button. And if I keep it at 25% width, the  text won't wrap.